# Adding variables to the global window object in IE

Tags: javascript

I have a situation where a link opens a new window(child) using Javascript. I am trying to pass a variable to the child window form the parent window by attaching to the new window's `window` object.

In the parent:

```
var wnd = open(file, name, attribs);
wnd.a = 10;
```

In the child when I do

```
window.a;
```

IE says undefined. This works on Chrome, Firefox and Safari.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: looks like ie is wrong, not you...

Comment: How is IE wrong? Window.open is DOM 0, there is no specification for it.

Answer (score 1):

Wait until the new window has loaded before setting the variable on its `window` object. In IE you may need to handle the `load` event within the new window rather than the main window.